# Why does RewriteRule ^page/?$ page.php [L] match site.com/page//

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/?$ page.php [L]
```

This ends up matching the url www.site.com/page// but internally it acts differently than www.site.com/page/ because the stylesheets and images no longer appear properly. Am I doing something wrong or is this just something I need to deal with if I don't want to go through a lot of trouble?

To me it looks like it should only match www.site.com/page or www.site.com/page/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache strips the empty path segment. So `/path//` is treated as `/path/`. But your browser doesn’t so relative URLs are resolved using `/path//`.

If you want to remove the multiple slashes, you can use the following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /(([^/\ ]+/)*)/+([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1%3 [L,R=301]
```

---

**Explaination**

Despite Apache removes empty path segments internal, the `THE_REQUEST` environment variable (holding the [HTTP request line](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1)) stays untouched. So we can use this value to check for multiple slashes.

- **`^[A-Z]+\ /`** matches the request method, the following space and the first slash character of the URI path.
- **`(([^/\ ]+/)*)`** matches all following non-empty path segments (`foo/`, `foo/bar/`, `foo/bar/baz/`, etc.) or nothing, if there are none.
- **`/+`** matches the empty path segments as the character before this slash is always another slash (see the expressions before).
- **`([^\ ]*)`** matches the rest of the URI (that may contain further empty path segments).

*Example:* Let’s say we request `http://example.com/foo/bar//baz`, the request line will look like this:

```
GET /foo/bar//baz HTTP/1.1
```

The pattern would then match as follows:

```
0: GET /foo/bar//baz
1: foo/bar/
2: bar/
3: baz
```

So the requested path `/foo/bar//baz` would be redirected to `/foo/bar/baz` (`/%1%3`).

Comment: Brilliant. Can you possibly explain a little bit what each of those lines do?